# replace the eval with something safer

Tags: javascript, jquery, eval, flatpickr

I created a calendar with the flatpickr.js library. I want to enable only the dates that are present in the arreys `dateCorfu`, `dateZante` and `datePag` selected from a dropdown (with the attribute name="destinazione").

I'm not a coder but I wrote the below code using the eval method, this is working but I'm sure that this is the wrong way.. maybe there is a better way to manipulate the result of function(date). So is there a way to make this to works without using eval?

```
flatpickr("#data-partenza", {
    locale:'it', 
    minDate: "2020-07-16",
    enable: [
        function(date) {
            // return true to enable
            var drop_destinazione = jQuery('[name="destinazione"]').val();
            var result = '';
            var dateCorfu = ["2020-07-16","2020-07-23","2020-07-30","2020-08-06","2020-08-13","2020-08-20"];
            var dateZante = ["2020-07-17","2020-07-24","2020-07-31","2020-08-07","2020-08-14"];
            var datePag = ["2020-07-18","2020-07-25","2020-08-01","2020-08-08"];
            var slice = 'date.toISOString().slice(0,10)';
            var i;
            if(drop_destinazione == 'Corfù'){
                for (i = 0; i < dateCorfu.length; i++) {
                    result += (slice + '==' + '"' + dateCorfu[i] + '"' + '||');
                }
                return eval(result.slice(0, -2));
            }
            else if(drop_destinazione == 'Zante'){
                for (i = 0; i < dateZante.length; i++) {
                    result += (slice + '==' + '"' + dateZante[i] + '"' + '||');
                }
                return eval(result.slice(0, -2));
            }
            else if(drop_destinazione == 'Pag'){
                for (i = 0; i < datePag.length; i++) {
                    result += (slice + '==' + '"' + datePag[i] + '"' + '||');
                }
                return eval(result.slice(0, -2));
            }
            else {
                console.log('no destination selected')
            }
        }
    ],
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y",
    disableMobile: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are only doing if-validations, why dont you just immediately **evaluate and accumulate** at each result += ..?

```
result = false;
for (...) {
    if (condition) result = true;
}
return result;
```

or even better: **exit early** like this:

```
result = true;
for (...) {
    if (condition) return true;
}
return false;
```

applied to your original code this would make your function look like this:

```
function(date) {
    var drop_destinazione = jQuery('[name="destinazione"]').val();
    var dateCorfu = ["2020-07-16","2020-07-23","2020-07-30",
                     "2020-08-06","2020-08-13","2020-08-20"];
    var dateZante = ["2020-07-17","2020-07-24","2020-07-31",
                     "2020-08-07","2020-08-14"];
    var datePag = ["2020-07-18","2020-07-25","2020-08-01","2020-08-08"];
    var slice = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    if (drop_destinazione == 'Corfù') {
        for (var i = 0; i < dateCorfu.length; i++) {
            if (slice == dateCorfu[i]) return true;
        }
    }
    else if(drop_destinazione == 'Zante') {
        for (var i = 0; i < dateZante.length; i++) {
            if (slice == dateZante[i]) return true;
        }
    }
    else if(drop_destinazione == 'Pag') {
        for (var i = 0; i < datePag.length; i++) {
            if (slice == datePag[i]) return true;
        }
    }
    else { console.log('no destination selected'); }
    return false;
}
```

however there are steps you can take to make your code less repetitive:

```
function(date) {
    var drop_destinazione = jQuery('[name="destinazione"]').val();
    var slice = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
    var allowed = {
        Corfù: ["2020-07-16","2020-07-23","2020-07-30",
                "2020-08-06","2020-08-13","2020-08-20"],
        Zante: ["2020-07-17","2020-07-24","2020-07-31",
                "2020-08-07","2020-08-14"],
        Pag: ["2020-07-18","2020-07-25","2020-08-01",
              "2020-08-08"],
    };
    if (allowed[drop_destinazione] == undefined) {
        console.log('no destination selected');
        return false;
    }
    return allowed[drop_destinazione].indexOf(slice) !== -1;
}
```

of course the property name "Corfù" does not look too nice, however "drop_destinazione" seems to be a dropdown, these have both a value and a label (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select). you should make the values simple strings like "corfu":

```
<select>
    <option value="corfu">Corfù</option>
    ...
</select>
```

if you do it like this, you can make the allowed index look nicer:

```
var allowed = {
    corfu: ["2020-07-16","2020-07-23","2020-07-30",
            "2020-08-06","2020-08-13","2020-08-20"],
    zante: ["2020-07-17","2020-07-24","2020-07-31",
            "2020-08-07","2020-08-14"],
    pag: ["2020-07-18","2020-07-25","2020-08-01",
          "2020-08-08"],
};
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for this, but your answer Is not clear to me. Can you please add some details..as I told I'm not a coder so maybe I'm missing some basics.

Comment: @silvered.dragon updated my answer to show you how to apply this principle in your code and how to further approve your code.

Comment: you are genious this solution return allowed[drop_destinazione].includes(slice); is really elegant. Thank you

Comment: I noticed that includes() doesn't works on IE11, do you have a fix for this?

Comment: you can also use array.indexOf(el) !== -1 instead of array.includes(el)

Comment: thank you for the reply I changed return allowed[drop_destinazione].includes(slice); to return allowed[drop_destinazione].indexOf(slice) !== -1; this is still working in chrome, but in IE the calendar is opening with no selectable dates inside.

Comment: ie is a pain - sorry i dont have access to an ie, so i cant debug myself, just some tips: do logging (add console.log() to each step and observe the output), or debugging (set a breakpoint and step through the code and look at variables) or simplify + expand (remove features to a minimum and put them back in one by one).

Comment: thank you my friend for your support, I'm sure that I will find a fix and I will report this to you.